# bash/sh nested escape sequences

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to understand how to write nested escape sequences in `sh`. I have to need illustrated by an example, I want to write something like this

```
sh -c sh -c sh -c sh -c sh -c date
```

Expected Output: current date

I tried the following, could go upto 2 levels of nesting but lost:

```
sh -c date
Sat May  2 18:38:38 PDT 2015
sh -c "sh -c date"
Sat May  2 18:38:43 PDT 2015
sh -c "sh -c \"sh -c date\""
Unmatched ".
```

I want a general purpose way to escape like the 5 levels of nesting shown above.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh, not Bourne, on modern systems. Bourne is a far older shell (70s, vs early 90s).

Comment: BTW, if working with bash rather than POSIX sh, the general-purpose way to escape arbitrary content to be passed to another shell is with `printf %q`. (Thus: As your question is explicitly asking about `/bin/sh`, it shouldn't be tagged `bash`; an answer for bash would be different).

Comment: "bash/sh" is as bad as "C/C++". They're two separate languages. They should get two separate questions, if you really need to know both.

Comment: Is there any sane reason to want to do this? Sounds like http://xyproblem.info/ to me.

Comment: I'm presuming that the real problem is escaping an arbitrary command to be sent over SSH (or otherwise used in a context where a shell is sure to reinterpret it), and that the question is posed as it is to ensure that the answer given is reasonably robust. At least, that's the only legitimate use case that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike POSIX sh, `bash` provides an explicit way to ask the shell to escape data to be eval-safe, with `printf %q`.

Thus, with bash:

```
$ command_str=date
$ nest() { printf 'sh -c %q\n' "$1"; }
$ nest "$command_str"
sh -c date
$ nest "$(nest "$command_str")"
sh -c sh\ -c\ date
$ nest "$(nest "$(nest "$command_str")" )"
sh -c sh\ -c\ sh\\\ -c\\\ date
```

...and so on, ad infinitum.

---

In POSIX sh, the third-party library [Push](https://github.com/vaeth/push) can be used for that same purpose:

```
$ source push.sh
$ command_str=date
$ Push -c command_str sh -c "$command_str"; echo "$command_str"
sh -c date
$ Push -c command_str sh -c "$command_str"; echo "$command_str"
sh -c 'sh -c date' 
$ Push -c command_str sh -c "$command_str"; echo "$command_str"
sh -c 'sh -c '\''sh -c date'\'
$ Push -c command_str sh -c "$command_str"; echo "$command_str"
sh -c 'sh -c '\''sh -c '\''\'\'\''sh -c date'\''\'\'
```

...etc.

---

If you wanted to automate the nesting for an arbitrary number of levels:

```
nest() {
  local cmd_str level >/dev/null 2>&1 ||: "in POSIX sh, local may not exist"
  level=$1; shift

  ## in bash
  printf -v cmd_str '%q ' sh -c "$@"; cmd_str=${cmd_str%" "}

  ## in POSIX sh, using https://github.com/vaeth/push
  #Push -c cmd_str sh -c "$@"

  if [ "$level" -gt 1 ]; then
    nest "$((level - 1))" "$cmd_str"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$cmd_str"
  fi
}
```

Then:

```
nest 5 date
```

...would give you (with `printf %q`, vs push)...

```
sh -c sh\ -c\ sh\\\ -c\\\ date
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming this is what you meant...

```
sh -c "sh -c \"sh -c \\\" sh -c \\\\\\\" sh -c \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" date \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" \\\\\\\" \\\" \" "
```

This gets pretty ugly, and honestly I'm not sure why you'd ever want to do this, but hey, there it is. Nest away!